# How to prevent object files creation in free pascal?

Tags: freepascal

I want to use static linking in free pascal & to get one compiled file output.

I specify `-o$outputName` and `-XS` parameters, but it still creates object files for all units, etc.

How i can tell compiler not to create such files (or delete them after job is done)?

Comment: @Marged E.g. they are necessary for compilation? I can do this using shell script, but i thought that there is specific compiler option for this.

Comment: @Marged i thought that if i delete *.o files it will crash, but it works fine. If there is no such option, so i will delete it with using shell command.

Comment: In fiew words: there are actually two programs used to produce executable: compiler (takes *.pas and produces *.o) and linker (takes *.o and produces executable). fpc just calls both one by one.

Comment: @Abelisto Thank you. Got it.